# Setting the labels on the x-axis of a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to graph the following data:

```
 ph1 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
 ph2 = ph3 = ph1

e1 = c(0.191, 0.154, 0.179, 0.073, 0.009)
e2 = c(0, 0.029, 0.054, 0.055, 0.024)
e3 = c(0.019, 0.027, 0.063, 0.029, 0.039)

set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(e1 = sort(runif(5, 0.05, 0.25)),
                   e2 = sort(runif(5, 0.05, 0.25)),
                   e3 = sort(runif(5, 0.05, 0.25)),
                   ph1 = sort(runif(5, 1, 100)),
                   ph2 = sort(runif(5, 1, 100)),
                   ph3 = sort(runif(5, 1, 100))
                   )
### reshape this to give a column indicating group
 df2 <- with(df1,
         as.data.frame(cbind( c(ph1, ph2, ph3),
                             c(e1, e2, e3),
                             rep(seq(3), each=5) )
                       ))
 colnames(df2) <- c("ph","maltose_in_mg","team")
 df2$team <- as.factor(df2$team)
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(df2, aes(x=ph, y=maltose_in_mg, col=team)) + geom_line()
```

...with the pH values (5 through 9) on the x-axis as labels. Unfortunately, the labels are being displayed from 0 to 100.

Edit (Note: Non-functional solution):

```
df1 <- data.frame(e1 = sort(runif(5, 0.05, 0.25)),
                  e2 = sort(runif(5, 0.05, 0.25)),
                  e3 = sort(runif(5, 0.05, 0.25)),
                  ph1 = sort(runif(1, 5, 9)),
                  ph2 = sort(runif(1, 5, 9)),
                  ph3 = sort(runif(1, 5, 9))
                  )
```

Comment: Your `ph` in `df2` ranges from 0 to 100.

Comment: Hi. Could you please check my edit above? My edit doesn't solve the problem and I'm stuck. Thanks.

Comment: With your new data frame the axes are correct (they range from about 5 to 8.5 on my machine)

Comment: Is the x-axis (ph) from 5 to 9? Could you show me how to display that specific range on the x-axis? I'm still learning R and ggplot2 so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but I think you are just asking how to make sure that the x axis goes from 5 to 9 regardless of your data? If so, you just want to add `scale_x_continuous(limits=c(5, 9))` to your existing plot. If not, you need to give more detail.

Comment: Could you tell me where I add scale_x_continuous(limits=c(5, 9)) in my plot? I have never seen that function before.

Comment: I would definitely not advise using scale_x_continous to set plot limits.  It throws away the data outside of the limits.  That may not matter in this case, but it will with regression lines, for example.  See my answer below using coord_cartesian, see how I use the + sign at the end?  That's how you link the components of ggplot together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do, but if it's not, please correct me.

I've put pH on the x-axis, and Maltose in Milligrams on the y-axis.

I also added a theme from the `ggthemes` package, which makes it pretty.  There are other themes you can find at the link I put in the code comment.

Finally, I limited the x-axis with `coord_cartesian` **(<-- that's what I think you were looking for, control over the range that's displayed)** and then `scale_colour_discrete` to put a nice looking title on the legend.

Next I added a title with `ggtitle` and axis labels.  The `theme_wsj()` has ggplot settings which you can view just by typing `theme_wsj()` into the `R` console.  It's default is to hide axis labels, I had to overide that with the `theme()` function and the bits inside of it.

`ggplot2` is an amazing package.  You can read all about it here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

```
install.packages("ggthemes")
library(ggthemes)

ph1 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
ph2 = ph3 = ph1

e1 = c(0.191, 0.154, 0.179, 0.073, 0.009)
e2 = c(0, 0.029, 0.054, 0.055, 0.024)
e3 = c(0.019, 0.027, 0.063, 0.029, 0.039)

set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(e1 = sort(runif(5, 0.05, 0.25)),
                  e2 = sort(runif(5, 0.05, 0.25)),
                  e3 = sort(runif(5, 0.05, 0.25)),
                  ph1 = sort(runif(1, 5, 9)),
                  ph2 = sort(runif(1, 5, 9)),
                  ph3 = sort(runif(1, 5, 9))
)

df2 <- with(df1,
            as.data.frame(cbind( c(ph1, ph2, ph3),
                                 c(e1, e2, e3),
                                 rep(seq(3), each=5) )
            ))
colnames(df2) <- c("ph", "maltose_in_mg", "team")
df2$team <- as.factor(df2$team)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x = ph, y = maltose_in_mg, colour = team)) + 
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(5, 9)) + # this is how you limit the axis range displayed, you can do the y, too with ylim = c(0, 1)
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Team") + 
  theme_wsj() + # find more themes here: https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes
  ggtitle("pH by Team") +
  ylab("Maltose in Milligrams") +
  xlab("pH") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = -0.075),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15))
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe add a figure so we can see the solution?